# Spring Security, JWT (REST) based Auth flow

Tags: rest, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to implement `JWT Token based` on my `SpringBoot 2.2.6` `REST` Backend, I would like to:

- Perform the *FIRST* *Authentication* retrieving user from `UserDetailService`
- If the *Authentication* goes well generate a `JWT Token`
- For the following access validate token **without access DB**

This is my Authentication Filter:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  protected JWTAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
    super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());
    // retrieve user from my userdetailservice
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
   // if Authentication goes well I generate the token and send it through the header response

    response.addHeader("Bearer ", "token");
  } 
}
```

This is my `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final ApplicationUserDetailService userDetailService;
  private final RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
  }

  @Bean
  public JWTAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
    JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter("/login");
    jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    ...
    return jwtAuthenticationFilter;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
}
```

Is this configuration correct?? It's a good idea to put another `OncePerRequestFilter` to parse a token (if present) or I should do all inside above authentication filter?

Thank you

------------------------UPDATE--------------------------

I'll try to put a filter to check if token is present and, if so, validate it - extract user and roles and put an `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` inside context. Therefore I override `doFilter` method of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` as follows:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  protected JWTAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
    super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = request.getHeader(SecurityConstant.AUTH);
    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

But, testing it, if I call a private path (that requires authentication) the `doFilter` method fired twice..

I put that filter before `BasicAuthenticationFilter.class`.. is there someone could explain me what's wrong??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved as follows:

First filter called:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String header = request.getHeader(SecurityConstant.AUTH);
    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstant.AUTH);

    if (token != null) {
      // parse token
        if (user != null) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

If path require authentication and token is not present:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

  protected JWTAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
    super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
  }

  public void setJwtUtilManager(JWTUtil jwtUtil) throws Exception {
    this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());
    // authenticate with userdetailservice
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    // generate token with jwtUtil
    response.addHeader("Bearer ", "token");
  } 
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/public").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    http.addFilterBefore(authorizationTokenFilterBean(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
}
```

I only have a doubt, I don't know how to handle `MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input` here:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());
    
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);
}
```

if I didn't pass `username` and `password` param inside request and `ObjectMapper` throw the above error.. hope helps.

Anyway asking here is really become useless..

Comment: I suggest that you create a separate endpoint to authenticate (instead of using `attemptAuthentication`). Because, for example assume you get `BadCredentials` error or even the error you are getting now. Since the filters are before the dispacher servlet, returning a response might get cumbersome. i.e. you have to redirect to `/error`....... better to leave it :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a separate endpoint to authenticate users and go with the token `JWTAuthorizationFilter` to filter incoming requests. One reason for recommending this is that, for example assume you get `BadCredentials` error or even the error you are getting now. Filters are executed before the `DispacherServlet`, so when there is an error it short cicuits before reaching it. In such occassions spring mvc sends post to `/error`, so if you have it setup it will fire it or else a default message will be sent back. Check this to handle the */error* endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/error")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBase> renderErrorResponse(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    ResponseBase response;
    Class<ResponseBase> responseClass = ResponseBase.class;
    try {
        Object status = httpRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        //you have the status, do what ever you like with it
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //hanlde 
    }
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.YYYY);
}
```

But, for me it seems a bit fishy. So I prefer not to use `attemptAuthentication()`. Instead create a controller for users to be able to get a token(for instance on login). And all calls are checked for a token(of course except the token generator and some public endpoints). So now you are sure that all calls arrive the `DispacherServlet` which allows you customize your exception handling as you like.